# Does WhatsApp start to upload every chat from the beginning, every time it starts a backup?

Tags: ios, backup, whatsapp.app

WhatsApp completed a backup today, it showed total size as 3.54 GB. Then, I pressed start backup again; it started showing "Uploading X MB of 3.54 GB". Does this mean it is uploading 3.54 GB of data again?

I thought it would only upload new messages which had come after the previous backup.

Does WhatsApp start to upload every chat from the beginning every time it starts a backup?

[image: Screenshot taken on iPhone of WhatsApp backing up]

<sup>(Click image to open full size)</sup>

Comment: https://faq.whatsapp.com/902477924463699/?helpref=tc_about&cms_platform=iphone doesn't mention anything about incremental backups. If you see full backups each time, that's probably the intended behaviour.

Comment: Everything seems to point to "yes" but there's no source to affirm that. :(

Answer (score 0):

As nohillside explained it could be the case. However, you can cross-check by just hitting backup and checking your data usage afterward.

> Uploads count towards your data cap for almost all internet providers[...](https://www.howtogeek.com/338593/does-uploading-count-towards-my-data-cap/)